# Add p-value to compare grouping variable in a descriptive statistics table in R

Tags: r, gtsummary

How would I add p-value to compare 2 groups according to the grouping variable, instead of comparing all subgroups. Here, after propensity score matching, the Not Performed and Performed groups seem to be matched but how to modify the p-values accordingly: [image]

I'm using "gtsummary" Package, this is my code:

```
tbl_1_m <- 
  df.match.CDS %>% 
 select(age_modified, sex, race_modified, marital_status_modified, year_of_diagnosis_modified, income_modified, primary_site_modified, laterality_combined, diagnostic_confirmation, surgery_modified, combined_stage, ajcc_stage, t_combined, n_combined, m_combined, radiation_modified, chemotherapy_modified) %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by= surgery_modified,
    missing = "no",
    type = all_dichotomous() ~ "categorical") %>% 
  bold_labels() %>% 
  add_p() %>% 
  modify_header(
    update = list(
      stat_1 ~ "**Not Performed**",
      stat_2 ~ "**Performed**"
    )) %>% 
  modify_spanning_header(
    c("stat_1", "stat_2") ~ "**Cancer-Directed Surgery**")
```

Comment: Hi , Ahmed Elkoumi welcome to SO. It will make it much easier to answer your question if you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/at/76995406/2530121). So run `dput()` on the data you are using e.g. `dput(df.match.CDS)`. Then, copy the result into a codeblock in your question. Also include _all_ the associated libraries you are using  in your codeblock as well. Thanks